# Adding register & login in Wordpress website

Tags: user-registration

I am adding register and login to WordPress website. I am using the following code:

```
<?php
        $c_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if( !is_user_logged_in( $c_user->ID ) ) :
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
            echo _e( 'Login', 'textdomain' );
        echo '</a>';
        wp_register('', '');
        else :
            echo 'Hello ' . $c_user->display_name;
        endif;
        ?>
```

After using the code, only the login text is showing. But I want to add "regsite & login". If the user is login, it should be replaced with display "name & logout" text

Comment: there are more related functions you could integrate into your code: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_loginout/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/

Comment: @Michael code you provide me the code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

integrating some of the suggested functions into your code:

```
<?php
        $c_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if( !is_user_logged_in( $c_user->ID ) ) :
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( 'Login', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
        echo _e( 'Login', 'textdomain' );
        echo '</a>';
        wp_register(' / ', '');
        else :
            echo 'Hello ' . $c_user->display_name . ', ';
            echo ' <a href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url( home_url() ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( 'Logout', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
        echo _e( 'Logout', 'textdomain' );
        echo '</a>';

        endif;
?>
```

some remarks:

- for the 'Register' link to show, you need to have ticked in the dashboard:
  'Settings' - 'General' - '**Membership** [ ] Anyone can register
- the 'Logout' will redirect to the home page; if you don't want that, remove `home_url()` from the code